# Why am I getting a segmentation fault in this code in the split function?

Tags: c++

```
int split(string stringSplit, char charac, string arraySplit[], int arrsize)
{
   if (stringSplit.length() == 0) 
   {
       return 0;
   }
   string word = "";
   int counterArray = 0;
   stringSplit = stringSplit + charac;
   for (int i = 0; i < stringSplit.length(); i++)
   {
       if (stringSplit[i] == charac)
       {
           if (word.length() == 0)
           {
               continue;
           }
           arraySplit[counterArray] = word;
           counterArray++;
           word = "";
       }
       else 
       {
           word = word + stringSplit[i];
       }
   }
   return counterArray;
}

int readRatings (string fileName, string user[], int ratings [][50], int numUsers, int maxRows, int maxColumns)
{
    if (numUsers == maxRows)
    {
        return -2;
    }
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open (fileName);
    string line = "";
    if (inputFile.fail())
    {
        return -1;
    }
    string arr [maxColumns];
    int counterUser = 0;
    int row = 0;
    while (getline(inputFile, line))
    {
        if (line.length() > 0)
        {
            int count = split(line, ',', arr, maxColumns);
            user [counterUser] = arr [0];
            counterUser++;

        }
    }
    return counterUser;
}
```

**This is only the first part of my code, and unfortunately we are only allowed to use commands in c++ that you see here, give or take. I can't seem to figure out why there is a segmentation fault. I'm guessing it is because it is trying to read an empty part of the array, but I can not figure out how to change that**

Comment: `stringSplit = stringSplit + charac;` From a quick glance, this looks suspicious. You are adding a character to a string array, not a string.

Comment: Can you post a small "main" to make it easy to replicate. Also, which line is producing the segmentation error ? Any debugger will let you know the location.

Comment: "I'm guessing it is because ..."  why guess?  Did you run in gdb (or your debugger)?  gdb typically identifies where a segfault occurs quickly.  All you need do then is climb the stack ('up' until you recognize the code) to inspect what is going on.

Comment: I'm a little new to coding so I'm no completely familiar with debugging, but when using the debugger and the segmentation error pops up, it highlights the portion "arraySplit[counterArray] = word". I will add a main to it right now as well

Comment: Won't let me add a main in the actual question, so here is this:

Comment: int main()
{
    string users[10] = {};
    int ratings[10][50] = {{0}};
    int numUsers = 0;
    int maxRows = 10;
    int maxColumns = 50;
    readRatings("ratings.txt", users, ratings, numUsers, maxRows, maxColumns);
}

Comment: In `split` function you add your results to the array but you never check if you reached the array size. So probably you write to an index which is out of bounds. It's better to use a `vector<string>` .